# Connecting to ET_Client using python

Tags: marketing-cloud, fuel-sdk

I'm trying to connect to ET_Client using python, in a Linux(Ubuntu) environment, and am having trouble overcoming the errors that are being thrown.

According to the sample code and tutorials I've read for FuelSDK, I needed to obtain a Client ID and Client Secret by crating an App in code@exacttarget. I've done that. I then read that I needed to make sure the Client ID and Client Secret exists in the environment variable. I've also done that, but still no love from FuelSDK.

Below is my code, and the error I'm getting.

```
import ET_Client

os.environ['FUELSDK_CLIENT_ID'] = 'gadffsdafasfasdfsdf'
os.environ['FUELSDK_CLIENT_SECRET'] = 'hfdsgsdfgsfasfasfad'

myClient = ET_Client.ET_Client()

ConfigParser.NoSectionError: No section: 'Web Services'
```

So I thought, maybe I shouldn't invoke ET_Client as though it's a function, but declare it like this:

```
myClient = ET_Client.ET_Client
```

However, after doing that, I got the following error:

```
TypeError: unbound method refresh_token() must be called with ET_Client instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
```

Can someone please explain what I'm doing wrong here? Has the SDK library changed? Should I be using it differently than how I'm using it currently?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

thanks,
Mark

Comment: I have always gotten this to work with the `config.python` file and not using the environment variables.  Have you tried it that way as well?  I'll dig in this morning a bit more, but just wanted to respond. Welcome to the community!

Comment: Thanks for your advice Kelly. I used your approach, and with a bit of tweaking, got it to work.

Comment: Feel free to add what you did and mark it as the answer so we all can benefit.  Glad it works.

Comment: Would you mind adding the answer below and marking as answered so everyone know what was done. Thanks!